# MCS meet all prime ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> let A be a commutative ring, is there any multiplicatively closed subset S (not containning 0), s.t. every prime ideal in A intercept S is not empty?

My thinking is that there is 1-1 corresponding between prime ideals in  A that not meet S, and prime Ideals in $S^{-1}(A)$, which imply there is no prime ideals in  $S^{-1}(A)$, and then can we conclude $S^{-1}(A)$ = $0$ so S contains $0$?

Comment: if your ring contains the unity, then what you wrote is correct. because the existence of unity makes sure that the ring has at least one prime ideal. but if the ring doesn't contain the multiplicative identity, then I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: @Krish yes, the ring A has 1. but I'm not sure if $S^{-1}(A)$ also has 1. And could u explain why a ring (has one) has at least on prime ideal?

Answer (score 1):

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity $1 \neq 0$. Then every proper ideal is contained in a maximal ideal. In particular, starting with the zero ideal we get that the ring $R$ has at least one prime ideal (may be the ideal (0) itself).

Now in this case, $A$ has identity $1 \neq 0$ (we can assume it because if $1 = 0$ then the ring is the zero ring and in this particular case we have nothing to prove!). Let $S$ be a multiplicatively closed subset of $A$ not containing $0.$ Suppose $S \cap \mathfrak{p}$ is non-empty for every prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $A$. Since the prime ideals of $S^{-1}A$ are in one to one correspondence ($\mathfrak{p} \leftrightarrow S^{-1}\mathfrak{p}$) with the prime ideals of $A$ which does not meet $S$, we get that there is no prime ideal in the ring $S^{-1}A.$ But this is not possible because $S^{-1}A$ is commutative ring with identity $1 \neq 0.$ The identity element of $S^{-1}A$ is just the image of the identity element of $A$ under the natural map $A \rightarrow S^{-1}A, a \mapsto \frac{a}{1}.$

(This is nothing but an explanation of what you wrote above.)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading this right, you're looking for an MCS which every prime ideal *intersects* the MCS nontrivially.

There is a very famous lemma that shows the answer is negative.

> Lemma: If $M$ is a multiplicatively closed (not containing $0$) subset of a commutative ring $R$ (with identity), then there is an ideal of $R$ maximal with respect to being disjoint from $M$, and this ideal is prime.

It is, for example, theorem #1 on page 1 of Kaplansky's *Commutative rings*. It's a very easy argument anyway. The poset of ideals disjoint from $M$ is nonempty (because $\{0\}$ is disjoint from $M$) and then Zorn's lemma can be applied to find a maximal element of the poset.

So given any MCS, you can find a prime ideal disjoint from it.